# Converting object to JSON format results in "{}"

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

```
[Serializable]
class temp
{
    int id;
    int age;

    public temp(int id,int age)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

    temp ob = new temp(4, 4);  
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(ob);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/User.json", json)
```

Hey guys I'm trying to convert my object to JSON and I'm getting "{ }"
any help?

Comment: Are you using this [JsonUtility.ToJson](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html)? "Generate a JSON representation of the ***public fields*** of an object." (My ***emphasis***)

Comment: For this to work you need to make the `id` and `age` fields **`public`**.

Comment: `int id;` -> `public int id {get; set;};`

Comment: Your properties aren't public.. And methods aren't serialized.

Comment: @Keshish don't use fields instead of properties. Properties aren't just access methods, they are part of the class's API while fields are just implementation that can change at any time. *All* serializers work with properties while only some work with fields and even then, only if instructed.

Comment: class User
`private string Username;
    private string PhoneNumber;
    private List<UserCar> UserCars=new List<UserCar>();`
what if i have another User Class and inside of it list of UserCars

Comment: `[Serializable]
public class UserCar    
{
    private string plateNumber;
    private string model;


    public UserCar(string plateNumber,string model)
    {
        this.plateNumber = plateNumber;
        this.model = model;
    }
}
`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what should I change in my code?

Comment: @mjwills Yes Sir it works as you see I added my actual code to the comment I have a username phone number and a list of user cars
what's your suggestion I'm writing a final project for the bachelor's degree I need to write it the most accurate way
like I'm not getting why to use the property when a field is enough for me I hope you can help me with that Thank you very much to y'all

Comment: `I'm not getting why to use the property when a field is enough for me` It clearly isn't enough for you **when it doesn't work**. Change your private fields to public properties. Serialisation, as a general rule, prefers properties to fields. Can you do it with fields? Yes. Is it harder? Yes.

Comment: @mjwills if I changed my field to public properties what about the list I should make public and that's it right?

Comment: Did it work when you tried it?

Comment: @mjwills Yes Sir but again if someone asks me why you're using public instead of private I think I can only tell them that if I used private my program won't work

Comment: @Keshish if derHugo's answer below helped you, consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read about Unity,s [Script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) you will find the rules for serialized values:

> Serializers in Unity run in a real-time game environment. This has a
> significant impact on performance. As such, serialization in Unity
> behaves differently to serialization in other programming
> environments. The following section outlines how to use serialization
> in Unity. To use field serialization you must ensure it:
>
> - **Is `public`, or has a `[SerializeField]` attribute**
> - Is not `static`
> - Is not `const`
> - Is not `readonly`
> - Has a fieldtype that can be serialized.

Note that by default in `c#` if you don't explicitly tell it otherwise the standard access scope is `private`  => Not serialized!

---

Your class should look like

```
[Serializable]
class temp
{
    public int id;
    public int age;

    public temp(int id,int age)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Or if for some reason you want to avoid the values being `public` then

```
[Serializable]
class temp
{
    [SerializeField] private int id;
    [SerializeField] private int age;

    public temp(int id,int age)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```